# Multiplication in Sobolev space with negative exponent

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

My initial problem is the following: I would like to estimate $\lVert f^2\rVert_{H^{-2}}$ in the sense of Sobolev embeddings, where $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a function defined on a bounded domain and $H^{-2}=W^{-2,2}=(W^{2,2}_0)^*$.

To have some intuition of what I should expect,let me fix the dimension to $4$, then we have $W^{1,2} \hookrightarrow L^4$, that is to say
$$\lVert f^2\rVert_{L^{2}} \leq C_\Omega\lVert f\rVert_{H^{1}}^2.$$
Now taking two derivatives less, I was expecting something like
$$\lVert f^2\rVert_{H^{-2}} \leq C_\Omega\lVert f\rVert_{H^{-1}}^2,$$
but it seems false!

So I am looking for some theorem of the form, let $s,s_1,s_2 \in\mathbb{R}$ and $p,p_1,p_2$ **satisfying some sharp relations** then
$$ W^{s_1,p_1} \times W^{s_2,p_2} \hookrightarrow W^{s,p}.$$

What I mean by sharp is that $W^{s_1,p_1}$ and $W^{s_1,p_1}$ must be as big as possible with respect to $W^{s,p}$.

Of course, $s=-2,p=2$ , $s_1=s_2$ $p_1=p_2$ will give me the space I was looking in my initial question.

The problem is that there seems few result about multiplication behavior of Sobolev space with negative exponent. At [Behzadan and Holst - Multiplication in Sobolev Spaces, Revisited](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.07379), I have found some cases with $s<0$ but not $s_1$ and $s_2<0$ (moreover it is on the whole space).

So any reference on this problem will be welcome?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** In view of Willie comment, I would like to rephrase my question: Assume that $f\in (W_0^{1,p})^*$ with $p<n$ in order that there is no Dirac in $(W^{1,p})^*$. This is equivalent to say that $f\in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ and there exists $g\in L^{p'}$ such that
$$f(\phi)=-\int \nabla \phi g.$$
how can I give a sense to $f^2$?

For instance I can define the multiplication
$$
\begin{array}{lll}
W^{1,p}&\rightarrow & L^1\subset W^{-?,?}\\
\phi&\mapsto&\phi f 
\end{array}
$$
Can I extend it by continuity from $W^{-1,p'}=(W^{1,p})^*$ to $W^{-?,?}$ choosing correctly the unknown space ?

**Test case:** let $\alpha>0$, $f=\vert x\vert^{\frac{-n-2+\alpha}{2}}=\partial_r \frac{ \vert x\vert^{\frac{-n+\alpha}{2}}}{\frac{-n+\alpha}{2}}  \in W_0^{-1,2}(B_1)$ and $f^2=\vert x\vert^{-n-2+\alpha}=\partial_{rr} \frac{\vert x\vert^{-n+\alpha}}{(-n+\alpha)(-n-1+\alpha)} \ll\in W_0^{-2,1}(B_1)\gg$.

Since the last inclusion doesn't make sense, we can modify the exponent to get

$f=\vert x\vert^{\frac{-n-4+\alpha}{4}}=\partial_r \frac{ \vert x\vert^{\frac{-n+\alpha}{4}}}{\frac{-n+\alpha}{4}}  \in W_0^{-1,4}(B_1)$ and $f^2=\vert x\vert^{\frac{-n-4+\alpha}{2}}=\partial_{rr} \frac{\vert x\vert^{\frac{-n+\alpha}{2}}}{\left(\frac{-n+\alpha}{2}\right)\left(\frac{-n-2+\alpha}{2}\right)} \in W_0^{-2,2}(B_1)$. Do we have $W^{-1,4}* W^{-1,4} \hookrightarrow W^{-2,2}$?

Comment: Negative exponent Sobolev spaces may contain distributions whose pointwise products are not well-defined as a distribution. Simplest example: in one dimension, $H^{1/2+\epsilon}$ embeds into $C^0$ and so $\delta \in H^{-s}((-1,1))$ for any $s > 1/2$. But $\delta^2$ is not defined as a distribution, and hence cannot belong to any Sobolev space (positive or negative index). Similar arguments (using $\delta$ of a single coordinate function) should rule out products when $s_1 < -1/p_1$ and $s_2 < -1/p_2$.

Comment: You right. In my example I consider $H^{-1}$ in dimension 4, so $H^1$ embeds in $L^4$ and not in $C^0$, then there is no $\delta$. My problem comes from differential geometry $f$ is a connection and I would like to control curvature. In dimension 4, Sobolev implies that gives $\Vert df + f\wedge f\Vert_2 \leq \Vert f\Vert_{H^1}$, I wonder if I can have such an inequality for Sobolev space with negative exponent. I can also assume that my connection is Coulomb if needed. As you mention I can't except to control by $\Vert f\Vert_{H^{-s}}$ with $s$ too big, but what is the best I can expect?

Comment: Let me clarify my previous comment a bit. Let $\delta^1$ denote the distribution representing the surface measure on $\{x^1 = 0\}$. Let $\chi$ be $\delta^1$ but truncated to have support in $B_1$. $\chi$ is in $H^{-1/2-\epsilon}$ since by trace theorem $H^{1/2+\epsilon}$ embeds into $L^2$ of the hyperplane, and boundedness of the support of $\chi$ shows that $L^2$ controls $L^1$. And so you can never do better than $s = -1/2$ _independently of dimension_. Whether the range $[-1/2,0)$ is admissible I am not sure, but do not have a good counterexample at hand.